# How can I get top 10 points?

Tags: javascript

My json file:

{"330805976192253952":{"pontos":4},"216277091019259905":{"pontos":1},"501035867759181829":{"pontos":2},"489520751536504833":{"pontos":8},"462609748181909504":{"pontos":1}}

How can I get the top 10 "Pontos"? But gonna be passing the JSON file as the same format.

Attempted code:

```
var pontosFile = JSON.parse(pontos); 
var top10 = pontosFile.sort(function(a) { 
  return a.pontos ? 1 : -1; 
}).slice(0, 10);
```

Comment: What have you tried already? Stack Overflow is here to answer specific questions, not really to provide the answer to a question in complete code.

Comment: I tried:var pontosFile = JSON.parse(pontos);
    var top10 = pontosFile.sort(function(a) { return a.pontos ? 1 : -1; })
                .slice(0, 10);

Comment: Please edit your question rather than posting comments with updates @PedroApprobato

Comment: How is `sort` going to work when there's no array to sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var pontosFile = 
{"330805976192253952":{"pontos":4},"216277091019259905":{"pontos":1},"501035867759181829":{"pontos":2},"489520751536504833":{"pontos":8},"462609748181909504":{"pontos":1}}

var top10 = Object.keys(pontosFile).sort((a, b) => {
    return pontosFile[b].pontos - pontosFile[a].pontos
}).slice(0, 10).map(k => pontosFile[k].pontos);

console.log(top10)
```